# Run shell script on specified external HDD mount

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I keep some files on an external HDD and I've wanted to know what is currently on it without connecting it.

I've modified [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060209130749352) command to get a .txt file with tree-like structure of my folders on that HDD uploaded to my iCloud Drive when I connect it to my MBP.

This is my edited command which I have saved as .sh, now saving the file to desktop:

```
ls -R /Volumes/2TB/ sed -e '/^[^:]*$/d' -e 's/://' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/ /' -e 's/-/|/' > /Volumes/SSD/Users/V/Desktop/File.txt
```

So far I've made a shortcut in BTT which runs the script but I would like it to run when I connect that HDD.

Someone suggested that I can could create a launchd with the StartOnMount key.
The problem is, as far as I understand from [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1676188?start=0&tstart=0), it's not possible to set up with specified volume.

Any ideas?

Comment: But what's the problem in running this script every time disk is mounted? You can make a script which checks if your specific disk is mounted, if not - exit.

Comment: How would you do that, then? I'm not an expert when it comes to terminal commands etc.

Comment: Please edit your post and show us your script.

Comment: Updated my question with command

Comment: So wrap this line with: `if [ -d "/Volumes/2TB" ]; then (...) fi`. This ensures the code will be executed only if the `2TB` volume is mounted.

Comment: Thanks @MateuszSzlosek, it works but I'll use the solution provided below instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example the output of `df` is piped to `grep` which is looking to match the hard disk mount point- `/Volumes/2TB`. The exit status of `grep` determines the outcome of the condition and the `!` reverses the logic.

```
if ! df | grep -q '\/Volumes\/2TB$'
then 
    exit 0
fi
```

In a sentence this says, if `grep` does not match `/Volumes/2TB` then exit the script.

I would write the script like this to put it all together.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
if ! df | grep -q '\/Volumes\/2TB$'
then 
    exit 0
fi

ls -R /Volumes/2TB/ |
    sed -e '/^[^:]*$/d' \
        -e 's/://' \
        -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' \
        -e 's/^/ /' \
        -e 's/-/|/' >/Volumes/SSD/Users/V/Desktop/File.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as described :) I'm running it via launchd agent with key 'StartOnMount'.